# Merge_sort without sentinel

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Can someone please tell me why I am getting garbage value after sorting?
Initial call is `(A,0,n)` where `n` is the size of array? I want to sort the array using merge sort algorithm but without sentinel value.

```
void merge_sort(int A[], int l, int mid, int r)
{
    int n1 = mid - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - mid;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        L[i] = A[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n2; i++)
    {
        R[i] = A[i + mid + 1];
    }
    cout << endl;

    int j = 0, k = 0;

    for (int i = l; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (j == n1 || k == n2)
        {
            if (j == n1 + 1)
            {
                A[i] = R[k];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                A[i] = L[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if (L[j] >= R[k])
        {
            A[i] = L[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            A[i] = R[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
}

void merge_divide(int A[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        merge_divide(A, l, mid);
        merge_divide(A, mid + 1, r);
        merge_sort(A, l, mid, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you use [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which are technically not part of the C++ language. Some compiler add them as non-portable extensions to the language though. I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: If you want to become a developer, a program can't be a black box for you. In other words, use a debugger and run your code step by step. What var values and compare with you expect.

Comment: What's up with the random `cout << endl;`?

Comment: Some part of the code considers the last element for the right subarray as   `A[r+1]`(your second `for` loop) , while other part of the code considers it to be `A[r-1]`(third `for` loop). This might lead to logical error and undefined behavior.

Comment: Replace all instances of `mid + 1` with `mid`. The code is using starting and ending (1 past last) indices (for example the initial call, 0,n, not 0,n-1). merge_sort is actually just a merge function. This means `n1 = mid-l` . `i <= n2` should be `i < n2`. I'm not sure I found all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of moves in your logic that is hard to read. It is hard to distinguish where is an error or there is some intention here. But here it is how I see it with fixes. See inline comments.

```
void merge_sort(int A[], int l, int mid, int r) {
  int n1 = mid - l;
  int n2 = r - mid;

  // this is C, but not C++, consider using vector instead
  int L[n1], R[n2];

  for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    // need `l` here
    L[i] = A[l + i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
    // need to include `mid`
    R[i] = A[i + mid];
  }

  int j = 0, k = 0;

  for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
    if (j == n1) {
      A[i] = R[k];
      k++;
    } else if (k == n2) {
      A[i] = L[j];
      j++;
    } else if (L[j] >= R[k]) {
      A[i] = L[j];
      j++;
    } else {
      A[i] = R[k];
      k++;
    }
  }
}

void merge_divide(int A[], int l, int r) {
    // need properly compute `mid` here
  int mid = r - l;
  if (mid > 1) {
    mid = l + mid / 2;
    merge_divide(A, l, mid);
    merge_divide(A, mid, r);
    merge_sort(A, l, mid, r);
  }
}

int main() {
  int A[] = {2, 4, 3, 382, 2342334, 3, 42, 234};
  int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);
  merge_divide(A, 0, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cerr << A[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: this solution worked for me... thanks @Yuki..but what was the fault in my code?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is hard to say where is an error, where is an correct logic and then an error. Just look at the difference of my code to your code (I tried to change as little code as possible), consider inline comments, then you can understand what you wanted and where it went wrong. I think the main problem was confusing indexes that you calculate and that you then use, or just totally wrong indexing.